# How to add raw() string to user generated string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to output my title with a special character, but it's converting the entire thing.

@title contains user generated content so i want to make sure it's escaped. It seems to be converting the entire string though and ignoring the raw. how do i do this so its still secure?

```
if @title.nil?
      "Web App"
    else
      "#{@title}" + raw(" &middot; Web App")
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in my views:

```
if @title.nil?
  "Web App"
else
  h("#{@title}") + raw(" &middot; Web App")
end
```

Comment: and this for sure won't allow for xss injection?

Comment: sorry that was a stupid question, i just looked up what h() does